# Android Kotlin Synthetic not working while app has multiple flavours

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

Kotlin release new kotlinx.android.synthetic which remove boilerplate code.
Kotlin Synthetic working fine while app has only one flavour.

In my case, there are more than 350+ flavours and some of have a different layout XML files. All other views ids are the same in all flavour and single Activity(Kotlin Class) for all these flavours.
My Kotlin class is in my main flavour.

So app structure is like :

1. For Class : app -> src -> main -> java -> MyActivity.kt
2. For main flavour : app -> src -> **main** -> res -> layout -> my_activity.xml
3. For flavourCoffee : app -> src -> **coffee** -> res -> layout -> my_activity.xml
4. For flavourTea : app -> src -> **tea** -> res -> layout -> my_activity.xml

When I try to import 
**import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_activity.***
it's working fine in the main flavour.

But when select different flavour it did not work.

Currently, I am using one tricky solution. Removed kotlin synthetic import and add below code then its working fine.

```
val tvUsrname = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvUsername)
```

and other 50 views will be there find view by ids.

But I don't want to write boilerplate code for findViewById.

Kindly tell me any other solution is there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One solution *(that I would not recommend)* is put same Class in all flavor specified folder and then import **flavor specific synthetic syntax**, another is *drop synthetic* and use other development way like `ButterKnife or Data-binding` etc.

Comment: even though i dislike data-binding, i agree this might be the right use for it @JeelVankhede

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes, even though synthetic imports are not useful for cross-module apps.

Comment: he man I just convert all code into kotlin and removed Butterknife.

Answer (score 1):

Since `kotlin-android-extension` is deprecated, you may use [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration).
I tried it for my flavors and it works great without any issues when change the active flavor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement fewer changes, a possible solution is calling `findViewById`. If you are working with fragment, you can do:

```
class TvgFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var myImage: ImageView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
        myImage = root.findViewById(R.id.my_image)
        return root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        myImage.set...
    }
}
```